# What could make a server going offline every 24hrs?

Tags: rhel, nfs

I have 8 servers, spread across two subnets (two separate switches), that all exhibit a maximum 24hr uptime. These are diskless machines mounting their filesystem from an NFS server. They go offline 24hrs after being started, give or take a few minutes. It doesn't matter what time of day they are started, they will go down 24hrs later at the same time.

I tried staggering their startup to see how consistent the 24hr period is, and they all went down in the same pattern they were started in.

When I check logs I don't find any evidence the machines are shutting down, or any indication of issues. I believe this is because whatever starts the crash is severing the connection to NFS.

Have tried updating to the latest kernel.

I am wondering if there are any services, or other potential causes that might be responsible for these symptoms. Please help!

Comment: If you believe that NFS is a problem source, please paste the relevant system log entries in your question so that contributors can get an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Random thought:, since these are diskless, are they getting their IP from DHCP?  If so, maybe something to do with lease times causing the network to renegotiate which drops NFS and kills the server?  (Lots of assumptions here.)

Comment: They are DHCP clients. Would this cause a dropout of NFS?

Comment: @omegacore That may well be something you may want to investigate. Check the DHCP server log to see whether clients get the same of different IP addresses, or if there is something else related to DHCP that may be a source of problems.

Comment: Are those servers physical? Are they in one datacenter? Do they have service processor (if hardware)?